# JPG Image Not Showing up in HTML

Tags: html, image, src, pythonanywhere

Everything else on my HTML page is showing up OK except my "cute_corgis.jpg" image. There's no "official" error, but only the image icon is showing up.

Here's my code:

```
<img src='cute_corgis.jpg' width='130' height='50' alt='Cute Corgis'>
```

The image is in the exact same folder as this HTML file, and the image name is correct. What's the problem?

P.S. I am using PythonAnywhere to run this webpage, if that's relevant.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use `./` as it doesn't know where to get the file from, `./` being the root directory the HTML is in.

```
<img src='./cute_corgis.jpg' width='130' height='50' alt='Cute Corgis'>
```

Answer (score 0):

See https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/StaticFiles/ for how to serve static files on PythonAnywhere